# Нужна помощь с формами action

Tags: php, html, form, action, index

У меня есть один файл например, `index.php`, и там есть кнопка, и вот если кнопку нажать, то должно выйти `index.php?action=button`, или `index.php?=button`.

Вот как такое замутить? Чтобы после нажатия кнопки появилась другая страница, но в файле `index.php`?

**Обновление**

```
<form method="get" action="mailbox.php?action=sent"> <li><a href="?action=sent"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> Sent</a></li> </form>
```

Я написал так,а теперь как внести изменения на странице `?action=sent`?

Теперь `if (isset($_GET['action'])) {echo 'action completed';}`

Comment: совет: пишите валидный код и тогда будет всё понятнее, оберните в <form> кнопку, не забудьте метод ( GET (именно он и добавит вам в url введёные значения)   или  POST) и action  - какому файлу направить для обработки (проверка наличия значений в переменным). Не забывайте про безопасность.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я понял из вопроса, вы хотите сделать какой-то простой роутинг. 
Советую почитать про [ЧПУ](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20url&oq=%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0j69i59j0l3.2654j0j1&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8), если хотите, чтобы всё было красиво. А в целом, конечно же, ещё и вообще про работу с GET и POST-запросами. 
Если ЧПУ не для вас, то по-простому можно сделать примерно так:

1. Делаете ссылку на страницу вида `<a href="?action=some_action">`
2. на странице index.php делаете проверку на наличие переменной `$_GET['action']`
3. если переменная существует и имеет необходимое значение, то инклудите файл с другой страницей, иначе инклудите какой-нибудь дефолтный файл.

В итоге у вас получается index.php как точка привязки, в которой инклудятся необходимые вам файлы при наличии необходимых переменных. В строке браузера всегда отображается что-то типа такого: http://mysupersite.ru/index.php?action=some_action

**UPD**
В самом простом виде это будет выглядеть примерно вот так:

`index.php`

```
if (isset($_GET['page'])){
    if ($_GET['page']=='gallery'){
        include('gallery.php');
    }
    elseif($_GET['page']=='contacts'){
        include('contacts.php');
    }
    elseif($_GET['page']=='about'){
        include('about.php');
    }
    else{
        include('error.php');
    }
}
else{
    include('default.php');
}
```

в файле `default.php` будет располагаться что-то примерно такое

```
<a href="?page=gallery">Галерея</a><br>
<a href="?page=contacts">Контакты</a><br>
<a href="?page=about">О нас</a><br>
```

Comment: То что надо спасибо,а можете уточнить как прописать путь к файлу?

Comment: И если можно обьясните пожалуйста как я понимаю "инклудите файл" это означает прописать путь к файлу через include?И как связать между собой инклуденный файл и `<a href="?action=some_action">`

Comment: Да, именно это я и имел в виду.
Добавил пример в ответ.

Comment: ,Спасибо вам большое,и вот последний вопрос: Когда я например беру кнопку в форму: `<form method="get" action="mailbox.php?action=sent">
                    <li><a href="?action=sent"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> Sent</a></li>
     <form>`                   так то меняется вид формы,так вот как сделать чтобы вид кнопки не менялся?

Comment: Честно говоря, не понял, что меняется и где. 
Лучше, наверное, вам это оформить как отдельный вопрос с подробным описанием, что вы сделали и что именно у вас не получается (какая ошибка выдаётся, или где скрипт ведёт себя не так, как вы ожидаете).

Answer (score 1):

```html
<form action="index.php" method="GET">
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="button">
  <input type="submit" value="button">
</form>
```

Comment: прочитайте уже какую-нибудь книгу по веб-программированию

Comment: @Ersultan Обновил вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать наиболее простую функцию.
Вот небольшой пример:
`echo "<div class='logo">Логотип</div>";
$act = isset ($_GET['act']) ? $_GET['act'] : '';
switch ($act) {
case 'page1' :
//Здесь код который выполниться если перейти на http://ваш_сайт/index.php?act=page1
break;
case 'test1' :
//Здесь код который выполниться если перейти на http://ваш_сайт/index.php?act=test1
break;
default:
//Здесь код который выполниться если перейти на http://ваш_сайт/index.php
}`

Comment: С этим я разобрался,но во всяком случае спасибо вам за отлик!